Problemas al referenciar la Hora con una instancia de Date() en Javascript
Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar mostrar dinámicamente la hora actual en un documento JavaScript. Específicamente, la hora no se está actualizando en la línea 18 de mi código HTML como se espera. El contenido de esta línea debería ser reemplazado con la hora actual, pero no está sucediendo o la actualización es solo temporal (solo sale en un flash y vuelve a aparecer el texto Hora).
Creo que el problema podría estar en la función tiempo que no se ejecuta correctamente. Aunque he usado setInterval para llamar a esta función cada 10 segundos, el elemento p en la línea 18 no se actualiza consistentemente. A veces se actualiza brevemente, pero luego vuelve al texto original 'Hora'.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda para averiguar por qué esto no funciona como se espera. Quiero asegurarme de que la hora se actualice cada 10 segundos y permanezca visible hasta la próxima actualización.
Aquí están los fragmentos de código relevantes:
Mi codigo HTML (Actividad_2.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Gerlando Terrasi">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   <!-- Aseguro que se visualice la página en dispositivos moviles. -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
<title>Actividad 2, Unidad 3</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/script_UD3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/estilos_UD3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div id="caja1"><img src="../Imagenes/Imagen 1.png" alt="Juegos Olímpicos"></div><div id="caja2"><h1>Encabezado principal</h1></div>
    </header>
    <div style="display: flex">
        <section style="width: 80%; height: 70%">
            <h1>Encabezado</h1>
            <p id="hora"></p>
            <article>
            <h2>Artículo 1</h2>
            <p>- El elemento de artículo representa un
            componente de una página que consiste en una composición
            autónoma en un documento, página, aplicación, o sitio web con la
            intención de que pueda ser reutilizado y repetido. Podría utilizarse
            en los artículos de los foros, una revista o el artículo de periódico,
            una entrada de un blog, un comentario escrito por un usuario, un
            widget interactivo o gadget, o cualquier otro artículo
            independiente de contenido.
            Cuando los elementos de de este tipo son anidados, los elementos
            de de este tipo que son interiores representan los artículos que en principio
            son relacionados con el contenido del artículo externo.</p>
            
            <h2>Artículo 2</h2>
            <p>- El elemento de artículo representa un
            componente de una página que consiste en una composición
            autónoma en un documento, página, aplicación, o sitio web con la
            intención de que pueda ser reutilizado y repetido. Podría utilizarse
            en los artículos de los foros, una revista o el artículo de periódico,
            una entrada de un blog, un comentario escrito por un usuario, un
            widget interactivo o gadget, o cualquier otro artículo
            independiente de contenido.
            Cuando los elementos de de este tipo son anidados, los elementos
            de de este tipo que son interiores representan los artículos que en principio
            son relacionados con el contenido del artículo externo.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <div id="caja3">
                <div><a href="https://www.nasa.gov/">Enlace de NASA</a></div><br>
                <div><a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/">Enlace de Khan Academy</a></div><br>
                <div><a href="https://www.bbc.com/">Enlace de BBC News</a></div><br>
                <div><a href="https://www.louvre.fr/es">Enlace de Museo Louvre</a></div><br>
            </div>
            <div id="caja4"> Los vínculos representan un menú de navegación</div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <footer id ="Pie">
     Pié de página
    </footer>
</body>

Mi código js (script_UD3.js):
window.onload= function() {
    /* alert(document.compatMode); */

    //Parte D: Muestra hora actual.
    let Fecha = new Date();
    console.log(Fecha.getHours()+":"+Fecha.getMinutes()+":"+Fecha.getSeconds());
    
    //Parte E: Hora actual en la página
    function tiempo(){
        let Actual = new Date();
        let hora = document.getElementById("hora");
        hora.innerHTML = Actual.getHours()+':'+Actual.getMinutes()+':'+Actual.getSeconds();
    }
    
    setInterval(tiempo, 10000);
}

También, por si acaso les hago envío de la hoja de estilos CSS (estilos_UD3.css):
        img {
        height: 80px;           /*le pongo este tamaño en expectativa de que haya un pequeño margen superior en el cual el haeder lo pinte del color verde ocre, como esta en la imagen*/
    }
    
    header #caja1, header #caja2 {      /*a cada caja dentro del header le asigno de altura el 100% dentro del header*/
        height:100%;
    }
    
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;                  /*Al header en si le doy como altura 100px*/
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: Arial, verdana, tahoma;
    }
    
    #caja1 {
        width: 13%;         /*Hallada por tanteo de cifras*/
        float: left;
    }
    
    #caja2 {
        background-color: #ADB96E;
        width: 87%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #caja3 {
        background-color: #C6D580;
        float: right;
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 14px;
        
    }
    
    #caja4 {
        background-color: #eadcae;   /*Por lo visto, no hace falta poner el codigo en mayúsculas*/
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    
    #Pie {
        background-color: #CCC49F;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    
    nav {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 15px;         /*Le habia añadido el padding con 10px como valor pero al parecer, pareciera que los hiciese con el margin. es raro.*/
    }
    
    #caja3, #caja4 {
        padding: 10px;          
    }
    
    nav div div {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #9ea775;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

Quiero mostrar la hora cada 10 segundos, de manera que la hora se muestre hasta la siguiente actualización. He intentado eliminar la etiqueta  de la línea 18 de 'hora' y reemplazarla con la etiqueta . He intentado usar el evento onload para llamar a la función tiempo con la instrucción:
<p id="hora" onload="tiempo()"></p>

Y aún así sigo teniendo problemas. En la función JavaScript tiempo, también he intentado reemplazar innerHTML con textContent e incluso llamar a la etiqueta de script al final del documento (en la línea antes de la etiqueta de cierre ) y aún así no funciona, tambien he intentado envolver todo el codigo JavaScript en una función con nombre (la llame Inicio()) y llamar esta funcion en la etiqueta body como sigue:
<body onload="Inicio()">

Lo que busco es que la pagina me muestre la hora y permanezca asi hasta que se vuelve a actualizar despues de 10 segundos. Validé las referencias a cada archivo y veo que no hay problemas con eso. No sé qué más hacer, necesito ayuda.

Por algún motivo veo que se te recarga la página, pero no alcanzo a ver donde; de todas formas si en lugar de usar setInterval usas setTimeout ya no tienes ese problema. A ver si esto te soluciona el problema
 window.onload= function tiempo(){
        let Actual = new Date();
        let hora = document.getElementById("hora");
        hora.innerHTML = Actual.getHours()+':'+Actual.getMinutes()+':'+Actual.getSeconds();
        setTimeout(tiempo, 10000);
    }


El problema es que la actualizas cada 10 minutos. A demás deberías de poner el reloj en general fuera del evento load.


setTimeout(tiempo, 1000); // La hora se actualiza cada segundo

window.onload= function tiempo(){
        let Actual = new Date();
        let hora = document.getElementById("hora");
        hora.innerHTML = Actual.getHours()+':'+Actual.getMinutes()+':'+Actual.getSeconds();
        // setTimeout(tiempo, 10000);
    }



